# How do I return the definition of a class in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, metaprogramming

Say I have a class "NumberStore"

```
class NumberStore(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def get(self):
        return self.num
```

And later on, for the purpose of serialization, I want to print a definition of the class, either exactly as stated, or equivalently stated. Is there any way in python to access a class's definition as in the idealized example below?

```
>>> NumberStore.print_class_definition()
"class NumberStore(object):\n    def __init__(self, num):\n        self.num = num\n    \n    def get(self):\n        return self.num"
```

Comment: Note that anything along these lines will fail for classes defined using free variables. The simplest example is a default parameter like `def meth(x=CONSTANT): ...`, but it also includes decorators (though many common decorators are built in and hence almost-universally available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, with [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource):

```
from inspect import getsource

class NumberStore(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def get(self):
        return self.num

    @classmethod
    def print_class_definition(cls):
        return getsource(cls)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks for the info. As a side note to those who haven't used this; it doesn't work in the interactive interpreter, you must have a python script or module being executed to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource).

```
import inspect
source_text = inspect.getsource(NumberStore)
```