# How to display definition of a class in Python

Tags: python, class, definition

I was going through this question : [How do I return the definition of a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095166/how-do-i-return-the-definition-of-a-class-in-python)

But I am unable to display the class definition. I am getting the below error:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> import inspect
>>> source_text = inspect.getsource(A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\**\Python\Python36\lib\inspect.py", line 968, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "C:\Users\**\Python\Python36\lib\inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "C:\Users\**\Python\Python36\lib\inspect.py", line 768, in findsource
    file = getsourcefile(object)
  File "C:\Users\**\Python\Python36\lib\inspect.py", line 684, in getsourcefile
    filename = getfile(object)
  File "C:\Users\**\Python\Python36\lib\inspect.py", line 654, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '__main__' (<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000026A79293F60>)> is a built-in class
>>>
```

Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Does python 3 even have old-style classes?

Comment: Why do you need to see the definition of a class you just defined yourself?

Comment: You can't show the definition because there is no source code left to retrieve.

Comment: @Chillie, I am not sure what do you mean by old style classes. I can define nad use classes in python3

Comment: @ jonrsharpe, I am just curious about concept of displaying the class definition. Let's say I am in the middle of the terminal and want to know the members of the class without living the python shell, I am new to python and trying to explore it

Comment: @Chillie: this has nothing to do with old-style classes. I'm not sure how this is relevant here.

Comment: @ForeverLearner then use `dir(some_object)`. It returns a list of attributes of an object, and should work on static members of a class. If you want to see values as well, you can do `some_object.__dict__`.

Comment: @ForeverLearner If you want to explore, explore the documentation of the class. Not its code. Sure you can find the members of the class by reading its source code, but you can't know if those attributes are internal or part of the public API - unless you read the documentation.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I tried to define the class with details and still got the same error >>> class MyClass:
...     variable = "blah"
...     def function(self):
...             print("This is a message inside the class.")
...
>>> import inspect
>>> source_text = inspect.getsource(MyClass)

Comment: @ForeverLearner: you can't use `inspect.getsource()` on anything that doesn't have a module file associated with it. Python doesn't keep source code around, and the interactive interpreter is *not a module file*.

Comment: @jules and  Martijn Pieters, ok. original question answer showed this trick hence I was curious.

Comment: @Aran-Fey , Yes I will explore the documentation, I am new to python and trying to take baby steps. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `inspect.getsource()` function only works if there is a *text file available to load the source code*.

You typed the definition of the class into the interactive interpreter, which doesn't keep the original source around when compiling that source into in-memory class and code objects.

Put your class definition into a module, import the module, and *then* use `inspect.getsource()`.

`inspect.getsource()` works by first finding the module for a given object (for classes, by looking at the `ClassObj.__module__` attribute for the module name, then getting the module via `sys.modules[modulename]`) then seeing if the module has a `__file__` attribute from which a readable source file can be determined. If there is such a filename and it can be read, then the `inspect` module reads that file to then search for the `class ClassName:` line and giving you all lines from that point on with same or deeper indentation. The interactive interpreter executes everything in the `__main__` module and there is no `__file__` attribute for the interpreter, so any attempts at loading source code for objects defined there will simply fail.

If you just wanted to know what members the class defines, use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) or [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) on the object instead. You don't need to see the full source code for that information.

Comment: Accepting this as an answer, able to retrive the source code when defined in another file. Thanks a lot. >>> import mod1
>>> import inspect
>>> source_text = inspect.getsource(mod1.MyClass)
>>> print(source_text)
class MyClass:
    variable = "blah"

    def function(self):
        print("This is a message inside the class.")

>>>